# TS: Combine generic type with default value of optional parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, default

I have the following function

```ts
function complete<T>(result?: T): void {
}
```

I want to add a default value for `result`:

```ts
function complete(result = null): void {
}
```

and in this case `T` to be infered as `null`. In the way that I could either call

```ts
complete()  // result: T = null
```

or

```ts
complete(valueOfSomeType)  // result: T = SomeType
```

I tried

```ts
function complete<T = null>(id: string, result: T = null): void {
}
```

but I'm getting the error

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'null'.ts(2322)
```

which makes sense as one could call

```ts
complete<SomeType>()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `function complete<T>(result: T = null as T): void { }` could solve the compilation error.

Comment: You might want to add the caveat that this does not prevent the unlikely event that someone calls `complete<SomeType>()` and gets the compiler to mistakenly believe that `null` is of type `SomeType`, and therefore faces any negative consequences of that.

Answer (score 2):

You could overload your function to either accept a parameter with the provided generic type or with no parameter and the default value `null`:

```
function complete<T>(result: T): void
function complete(): void
function complete<T>(result: T | null = null): void {
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgGwKZWwHgBUA+ACgCdsBnETKALkUIEpGA3OGAEwFgAoUJFgJkaLLmylWiDt36Do8JCgw48RMpRp1GhRAB9EYWpkQBeIyemyuiAN78Avv34rxeKQG5EAeh9NzS0xMVzE1SQBGACYAZmZvPwCLY1QAI2xyUNUJfBT08jJ4338ABQBDcjLUCXJESgBHEBhKWwB3GCgAC0QoAE90bEQKgHMQarAoIA)